# rsyslog seems to have vanished from my system

Tags: ubuntu, logs, email, rsyslog

I'm debugging an issue where I think my server is spamming other servers because it is infected but all my logs stop in august last year, and rsyslog is missing from the system /etc/rsyslog.d still exists and clearly it was writing logs once but there are no new logs being generated for /var/log/mail.log or /var/log/messages

but running

```
rsyslog
```

results in command not found, should I run:

```
apt-get install rsyslog
```

and then

```
service rsyslog start
```

and has any one seen anything like this before?

Comment: try `rsyslogd`.

Comment: it says command not found and unrecognized service

Comment: `which rsyslogd` ?

Comment: no output is given

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /usr/sbin/rsyslogd`?

Comment: Does you system have it ? `find /usr -name "rsyslog*"`, else just install it ...

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal and execute the command

```
# sudo add-apt-repository ppa:adiscon/v8-stable
```

Now install rsyslog

```
# sudo apt-get install rsyslog
```

to check rsyslog version,

```
# rsyslogd -v
rsyslogd 7.4.4, compiled with:
    FEATURE_REGEXP:             Yes
    FEATURE_LARGEFILE:          No
    GSSAPI Kerberos 5 support:      Yes
    FEATURE_DEBUG (debug build, slow code): No
    32bit Atomic operations supported:  Yes
    64bit Atomic operations supported:  Yes
    Runtime Instrumentation (slow code):    No
    uuid support:               Yes
```

Also check whether your [rsyslog running](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217345/figure-out-rsyslog-listening-port-number/217358#217358)

Comment: I **wouldn't suggest** installing `rsyslog` from a PPA - that's unnecessary. If the original poster doesn't have it installed, they can reinstall from the official Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 1):

I've re-installed it using

```
apt-get install rsyslog
```

and logs seem to be filling up again, odd that it seems to have gone missing in the first place, it's clearly been on the system before

Comment: Lots of malicious attacks involve disabling logging or redirecting logs to `/dev/null`. Its an early step after compromising a system, in order to avoid an audible trail. You might want to be suspicious of the system on the whole IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that You are running systemd.

Look in /var/log/README

```
You are running a systemd-based OS where traditional syslog has been
replaced with the Journal.
```