# Figure out Rsyslog listening port number

Tags: rsyslog

On my ubuntu 14.04 machine, rsyslog service is running healthily...

`service rsyslog status` returns,

```
rsyslog start/running, process 794
```

`cat /proc/794/cmdline` shows,

```
rsyslog  #meaning rsyslog is running with default params.
```

Now, i am trying to check if rsyslog is having a TCP/UDP listening connection on port 514 using,

```
netstat -lnup | grep 514   #for udp
netstat -lntp | grep 514   #for tcp
```

Both of the netstat commands return empty.

Still, how can it run a server without a listening port?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

rsyslog doesn't listen on INET sockets by default. Instead, it binds to `/dev/log`, which is a [Unix domain socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket).

```
# ls -la /proc/$(pidof rsyslogd)/fd
total 0
dr-x------ 2 root root  0 Jul 20 11:28 .
dr-xr-xr-x 7 root root  0 Jul 20 11:05 ..
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jul 20 11:28 0 -> socket:[3559]
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Jul 20 11:28 1 -> /var/log/syslog
...

# netstat -x | grep 3559
unix  19     [ ]         DGRAM                    3559     /dev/log
```

Answer (score 1):

check the below command too,

```
# netstat -anp | grep rsyslogd

 unix  9      [ ]         DGRAM                    74832746 5570/rsyslogd       /dev/log
```

or

```
 # netstat -anp | grep 514
    tcp        0      0 192.168.122:45405        192.168.0.210:514          ESTABLISHED 5570/rsyslogd       
    tcp        0      0 192.168.122:45459        192.168.0.210:514          ESTABLISHED 5570/rsyslogd
```

Answer (score 0):

netstat looks to be deprecated in CentOS 7. Use ss command like below

```
ss -tulpn | grep 514
```

You could also identify the ports used from rsyslog conf:

```
sudo less /etc/rsyslog.conf
```

Comment: When the port number is to be found out, you *cannot* use the port number and query  for the process.